# Redirect visitor with .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I've got an e-shop on a virtual server that's been used as a subdirectory for the last few years, but now I'm finally giving the VS it's own domain name. What I really need is visitors to the old URL to be transparently (and 301) redirected to the new URL with everything after /eshop/ maintained and apended to the new host.

I.e. http://www.example.com/eshop/page.php -> http://www.newdomain.com/page.php

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify which web server you were using, but I assume its either apache or lighttpd.

In apache, you can use the Redirect keyword, e.g.
Redirect 301 /  http://www.newdomain.com/
I haven't tried this, but see e.g. here:
http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ApacheRedirect.html#APACHE
It seems to work with .htaccess files as well.

In lighttpd, there is mod_redirect (and I *did* try this :) ):
http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModRedirect

**EDIT:**
`Redirect 301 /eshop/ http://www.newdomain.com`

Comment: Hi Krumelur - thanks for your response, yep I've browsed a variety of .htaccess resources but I'm not too great with regex for getting the path correct, any ideas? I.e. as in the example above, I need to match the condition of: if http://www.example.com/eshop/$ is found, everything denoted by $ (following the URL) is copied and the visitor is 301 redirect to http://www.newdomain.com/$ where $ is the content we copied from the old URL...

Comment: Have you tried the following?
`Redirect 301 /eshop/ http://www.newdomain.com`

That would redirect everything below eshop, e.g.
`http://www.example.com/eshop/page1 -> http://www.newdomain.com/page1`

Answer (score 1):

This should work with Apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/eshop(/.*)? http://www.newdomain.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

This redirects http://www.example.com/eshop/whatever to http://www.newdomain.com/whatever and also redirects http://www.example.com/eshop to http://www.newdomain.com